# How backwards compatible are the various versions of Mac OSX? (Xcode C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, backwards-compatibility

I'm working on a game using C++ and relying on legacy features of OpenGL.

I've mostly been doing programming on Windows machines and am now looking into expanding into Linux and Mac OS. As a personal challenge, I'd like to keep my software as backwards-compatible as possible and support as many OSes as possible. With Windows, I've been able to upkeep support for as low as Windows 95 (with Visual Studio giving me some trouble in the process but working it out nevertheless). However, I have next to no knowledge of Mac OS, having never used it myself until just now. Considering my software runs on Windows 95, it certainly does not require any advanced features on functions.

The lowest version of Mac OS that old versions of Xcode seems to support is 10.1.x. If I was to write software for this version of Mac OS, would it run on more modern versions of Mac OS? I've read that there are software patches that enable support for some older MacOS software on never versions but I would rather not inconvenience the end user like that.
I would not mind building two different versions of the software (say, a legacy and modern launcher) but having to build five or ten different versions of the software would be a massive pain and I'd rather avoid that if at all possible.

I apologize for my lack of knowledge in the field, my own research has only yielded very limited information and I would rather not waste weeks on a fruitless endeavor.

TL;DR: I want to write software in Xcode (C++) for Mac OSX that supports as many versions of the OS as possible. If I was to target Mac OS version 10.1, can I expect it to run on modern versions of Mac OS? If not, how much effort would it take to support as many versions of Mac OS as possible?

Comment: Mac OS X is now macOS to give you an idea of how backwards compatible things are going to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to make a decision as to where you're going to cut off support, or you're going to have to build multiple versions of the app in different specially-built build environments.

Modern macOS (10.15) is strictly 64-bit x86-64 only, zero support for 32-bit apps. If you build on 10.15 you can't even build a 32-bit image. If you did it would be linked against libraries that don't exist on older versions of the OS.

Mac OS X 10.6 was the last 32-bit x86 version that shipped, but was also the first 64-bit version of the OS, as it represented the transition to 64-bit. It was also the last PowerPC version that shipped.

If you want to support PowerPC machines, which was the only option in the 10.1 days, you'll need a compatible system to build it.

Ecosystem-wise, most Mac users are able to run current versions of the OS. Anything 2012+ is still able to get current OS releases, which is a lot of hardware. Anything before that is a mix of 32-bit and PowerPC hardware, though you won't see a lot of people with systems like that in the wild.

In short, 10.15 is easy, 10.14 and 10.13 aren't going to be hard. Anything beyond that will be various degrees of challenging, but beyond 10.6 things will get super complicated.

One way to estimate popularity is things like the [Steam Hardware Survey](https://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey/Steam-Hardware-Software-Survey-Welcome-to-Steam?platform=mac) where the breakdown looks like this:

- 10.15: 31.6%
- 10.14: 34.1%
- 10.13: 14.8%
- 10.12: 5.7%
- 10.11: 3.7%

So the good news is things drop off pretty steeply after 10.13 and by 10.11 there's not many users running an OS that old.

Comment: Like I mentioned, my targeting of old OSX versions is a personal challenge more than anything. I doubt there are many people still running Windows 95 either but it's a fun experiment nevertheless. Based on what you've described, what is the likelihood of a program built of OSX 10.6 to run successfully on versions 10.7 to 10.14? Is it somewhat like Windows XP, whose programs mostly run with little trouble on Windows 7, or is compatibility much more fickle on OSX?

Comment: It's really hard to say, as different iterations of the same OS changed how backwards/forwards compatible they are, and this goes doubly for the various versions of XCode produced over the years. I don't think you'd have to make a lot of code changes per-se, but you will need to fuss and fiddle with getting your build environments set up just *so*.

Comment: The Windows code-base is all about backwards compatibility, some apps from *Windows 1.0* continue to work just fine, as you can even run [16-bit apps in Windows 10](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-16-bit-application-support-windows-10/) if you need to. macOS has a different philosophy, Apple burns the underbrush and cleans house on certain compatibility stubs on a regular basis. A Mac app from 2012 probably won't run today unless recompiled 64-bit, yet a Windows app from 1992 might run just fine.

Comment: `Anything before that is a mix of 32-bit and PowerPC hardware` is not correct, there are quite a few 64-bit models that are from before 2012 and no longer supported by the latest os.

Comment: macOS supports [multiarchitecture ("fat") binaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary#Apple's_Universal_binary), which can include code for as many different CPU architectures as you want. I haven't experimented much with this, but I think you could do pretty well by combining a 32-bit PPC binary for 10.1 - 10.5 (10.6 dropped support for PPC CPUs), a 32-bit Intel binary for 10.4 - 10.6 (10.7 dropped support for 32-bit Intel CPUs), and a 64-bit Intel binary for 10.5 - 10.15. No single complier will build all of these, but the `lipo` command can combine from different sources.

Comment: @GordonDavisson What's the earliest version that supports fat binaries? Thought that was 10.4 or thereabouts.

Comment: @tadman AIUI support for fat binaries carried over from NeXTStep, so it was there in Mac OS X from the very beginning. Apple only started *using* it for anything with the release of Intel Macs (running 10.4).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Intriguing. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @tadman BTW, early versions of Mac OS X supported both Mach-O executable formats (inherited from NeXTStep) and [Preferred Executable Format (PEF) aka Code Fragment Manager (CFM) executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_Executable_Format) (inherited from pre-X MacOS), and PEF *also* supported "fat" binaries (for 68K and PPC). See chapter 7 of [Mac OS Runtime Architectures - For System 7 Through Mac OS 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/mac/pdf/MacOS_RT_Architectures.pdf). But I don't think it's possible to combine PEF and Mach-O formats.